# How do you implement a jump search for object arrays in a java program?

Tags: java

So I'm still learning about java and I'm trying to implement jump search to find data based on no_resi inside an array of objects .

I understand when doing it array of int but i am still confused how to do it with array of objects. I already tried doing stuff with it but still cannot get my head around it or maybe i'm just stupid.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Here are my code

JumpSearch.java

```
public class JumpSearch {

    public static int jumpsearch(Pengiriman[] arrayPengiriman, int no_resi) {

        int n = arrayPengiriman.length; 

        // Mencari ukuran blok untuk dilompati
        int step = (int)Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n)); 


        // Mencari blok tempat elemen berada
        // present (kalau elemet present) 
        int prev = 0; 
        while (arrayPengiriman[1-Math.min(step, n)] < no_resi)
        { 
            prev = step; 
            step += (int)Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n)); 
            if (prev >= n) 
                return -1; 
        } 

        // Melakukan linear search untuk x di dalam blok
        // dimulai dengan prev
        while (arrayPengiriman[1-Math.min(step, n)] < no_resi) 
        { 
            prev++; 

            // Jika mencapai blok berikutnya atau akhir
            // array, elemen tidak ada.
            if (prev == Math.min(step, n)) 
                return -1; 
        } 

        // Jika elemen ditemukan
        if (arrayPengiriman[prev] == no_resi) 
            return prev; 

        return -1; 
    } 


    // Program untuk menguji fungsi
    public static void main(String [ ] args) 
    {      
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
        System.out.println("|    PROGRAM PENCARIAN DATA PENGIRIMAN BARANG DENGAN ALGORITMA JUMP SEARCH     |");
        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
        System.out.println("|Kasus Mencari Data Pengiriman Dengan No.Resi Menggunakan Algoritma Jump Search|");   
        System.out.println("");

        // Array untuk menampung nilai tiap Data
        Pengiriman[] arrayPengiriman = new Pengiriman[16];                 

        Pengiriman kirim1 = new Pengiriman (101101,"Adam Kamil","Jl.Anggrek","Bogor","Gunungbatu","16118"); 
        Pengiriman kirim2 = new Pengiriman (101102,"Putra Mandala","Jl.Apel","Kerawang","Kerawang Barat","41311"); 
        Pengiriman kirim3 = new Pengiriman (101103,"Mamat Sanusi","Jl.Merpati","Jakarta Selatan","Lenteng Agung","12610"); 
        Pengiriman kirim4 = new Pengiriman (101104,"Kamila Akhwan","Jl.Kelapa","Bekasi","Bekasi Timur","17111"); 
        Pengiriman kirim5 = new Pengiriman (101105,"Putra Iskandar","Jl.Anggrek 2","Bogor","Menteng","16111"); 
        Pengiriman kirim6 = new Pengiriman (101106,"Nabila Putri","Jl.Merapi","Palu","Tatanga","94239");
        Pengiriman kirim7 = new Pengiriman (101107,"Imam Satya","Jl.Pulau Nias","Manado","Bunaken","95231"); 
        Pengiriman kirim8 = new Pengiriman (101108,"Robby Dermawan","Jl.Tajung Pura","Yogyakarta","Gondokusuman","55225"); 
        Pengiriman kirim9 = new Pengiriman (101109,"Adrian Suta","Jl.Dewi Sartika","Banggai","Luwuk","94712"); 
        Pengiriman kirim10= new Pengiriman (1011010,"Rizky Prima","Jl.Gunung Jati","Jayawijaya","Wamena","99511"); 
        Pengiriman kirim11 = new Pengiriman (1011011,"Margareth Warouw","Jl.Sawit","Jakarta Timur","Cibubur","13720"); 
        Pengiriman kirim12 = new Pengiriman (1011012,"Jeni Indira","Jl.Tuna","Bekasi","Bekasi Barat","17136"); 
        Pengiriman kirim13 = new Pengiriman (1011013,"Asep Suratman","Jl.Palapa","Bogor","Margajaya","16116"); 
        Pengiriman kirim14 = new Pengiriman (1011014,"Gigi Purnama","Jl.Keraton Atas","Bekasi","Setu","17320"); 
        Pengiriman kirim15 = new Pengiriman (1011015,"Kamila Dewi","Jl.Dago Timur","Bandung","Coblong","40135"); 
        Pengiriman kirim16 = new Pengiriman (1011016,"Desy Sambeta","Jl.Proklamasi","Surabaya","Wonocolo","60239"); 

        //memasukan data mahasiswa ke dalam array
        arrayPengiriman[0]=kirim1;
        arrayPengiriman[1]=kirim2;
        arrayPengiriman[2]=kirim3;
        arrayPengiriman[3]=kirim4;
        arrayPengiriman[4]=kirim5;
        arrayPengiriman[5]=kirim6;
        arrayPengiriman[6]=kirim7;
        arrayPengiriman[7]=kirim8;
        arrayPengiriman[8]=kirim9;
        arrayPengiriman[9]=kirim10;
        arrayPengiriman[10]=kirim11;
        arrayPengiriman[11]=kirim12;
        arrayPengiriman[12]=kirim13;
        arrayPengiriman[13]=kirim14;
        arrayPengiriman[14]=kirim15;
        arrayPengiriman[15]=kirim16;



        Pengiriman tampilPengiriman = new Pengiriman();

        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
        System.out.println("|                                DATA PENGIRIMAN                               |");
        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
        System.out.println("");

        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        //Menampilkan Array yang sudah disorting secara Ascending    
        tampilPengiriman = arrayPengiriman[i];

        System.out.print("  "+(i+1)+". ");
        System.out.print(tampilPengiriman.getNoResi()+" ");
        System.out.print(tampilPengiriman.getNamaPengirim()+" ");
        System.out.print(tampilPengiriman.getAlamatTujuan()+" ");
        System.out.print(tampilPengiriman.getKotaTujuan()+" ");
        System.out.print(tampilPengiriman.getKecamatanTujuan()+" ");
        System.out.println(tampilPengiriman.getKodePosTujuan()+" ");

        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");


        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
        System.out.println("|                               CARI DATA PENGIRIMAN                           |");
        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
        System.out.println("");

        //Memasukan 'noRes'
        System.out.print("\n    Masukkan No Resi yang ingin dicari datanya : ");
        int no_resi = scan.nextInt(); 

        // Mencari index dari 'x' dengan jump search
        int index = jumpsearch(arrayPengiriman, no_resi); 

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");


        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
        System.out.println("|                       HASIL PENCARIAN DATA PENGIRIMAN                        |");
        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
        System.out.println("");

        // Menampilkan index dimana 'x' ditemukan
        if (no_resi != -1 && index != -1) {
          System.out.println("\n Data pengiriman barang dengan" + no_resi + 
                            " ditemukan di index ke " + index); 
        } else {
          System.out.println("\n Data pengiriman dengan No Resi" + no_resi + 
                            " tidak ditemukan"); 
        }
        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
    }
}
```

Pengirman.java

```
public class Pengiriman{

    private int no_resi;
    private String nama_pengirim;
    private String alamat_tujuan;
    private String kota_tujuan;
    private String kecamatan_tujuan;
    private String kode_pos_tujuan;

    public Pengiriman(){
        this.no_resi = 0;
        this.nama_pengirim = "";
        this.alamat_tujuan = "";
        this.kota_tujuan = "";
        this.kecamatan_tujuan = "";
        this.kode_pos_tujuan = "";
    }

    public Pengiriman(int no_resi,String nama_pengirim, String alamat_tujuan,
            String kota_tujuan, String kecamatan_tujuan, String kode_pos_tujuan){
        this.no_resi = no_resi;
        this.nama_pengirim = nama_pengirim;
        this.alamat_tujuan = alamat_tujuan;
        this.kota_tujuan = kota_tujuan;
        this.kecamatan_tujuan = kecamatan_tujuan;
        this.kode_pos_tujuan = kode_pos_tujuan;
    }

    public int getNoResi() {
        return no_resi;
    }
    public void setNoResi(int no_resi) {
        this.no_resi = no_resi;
    }
    public String getNamaPengirim() {
        return nama_pengirim;
    }
    public void setNamaPengirim (String nama_pengirim) {
        this.nama_pengirim = nama_pengirim;     
    } 
    public String getAlamatTujuan() {
        return alamat_tujuan;
    }
    public void setAlamatTujuan (String alamat_tujuan) {
        this.alamat_tujuan = alamat_tujuan;     
    } 
    public String getKotaTujuan() {
        return kota_tujuan;
    }
    public void setKotaTujuan (String kota_tujuan) {
        this.kota_tujuan = kota_tujuan;     
    } 
    public String getKecamatanTujuan() {
        return kecamatan_tujuan;
    }
    public void setKecamatanTujuan (String kecamatan_tujuan) {
        this.kecamatan_tujuan = kecamatan_tujuan;     
    }     
    public String getKodePosTujuan(){
        return kode_pos_tujuan;
    }
    public void setKodePosTujuan (String kode_pos_tujuan) {
        this.kode_pos_tujuan = kode_pos_tujuan;     
    }    
}
```

Comment: I would recommend `implement Comparable<Pengiriman>` for your Pengiriman class, so that it would be easier to compare. (you wouldn't have to write the way to do it each time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part your code works fine however there are a few minor things here to take care of and others to consider. Let's start with the **Pengiriman** class.

In your **Pengiriman** class you have a typical constructor which accepts no parameters and within that constructor you default all class member variables to either **0** or Null String (**""**). You can eliminate this additional code if you merely initialize your variables where declared. This would make those values default whenever a new instance of **Pengiriman** is created, for example:

```
public class Pengiriman{

    private int no_resi = 0;
    private String nama_pengirim = "";
    private String alamat_tujuan = "";
    private String kota_tujuan = "";
    private String kecamatan_tujuan = "";
    private String kode_pos_tujuan = "";

    public Pengiriman(){  }

    // ....     Overloaded Contructor(s)      ....

    // ....       Getters and Setters         ....  

    // ....  Nice to have a toString() method  ....
}
```

If this above constructor is used, class Setter methods will need to be used in order to fill those variables with something other than the default values they were initialized with:

```
Pengiriman p = new Pengiriman();
p.setNoResi(101109);
```

Your other (overloaded) constructor within the class accepts all class member variables as parameters. This is good and makes life a little easier when creating an array of the object so, when creating the array all you need to do is:

```
Pengiriman[] arrayPengiriman = new Pengiriman[16];

arrayPengiriman[0] = new Pengiriman(101101, "Adam Kamil", "Jl.Anggrek", "Bogor", "Gunungbatu", "16118");
arrayPengiriman[1] = new Pengiriman(101102, "Putra Mandala", "Jl.Apel", "Kerawang", "Kerawang Barat", "41311");
arrayPengiriman[2] = new Pengiriman(101103, "Mamat Sanusi", "Jl.Merpati", "Jakarta Selatan", "Lenteng Agung", "12610");
// .....  etc.  .....
```

You **do not** need to do something like this as well (it can therefore be deleted):

```
arrayPengiriman[0] = kirim1;
arrayPengiriman[1] = kirim2;
arrayPengiriman[2] = kirim3;
arrayPengiriman[3] = kirim4;
arrayPengiriman[4] = kirim5;
arrayPengiriman[5] = kirim6;
arrayPengiriman[6] = kirim7;
arrayPengiriman[7] = kirim8;
arrayPengiriman[8] = kirim9;
arrayPengiriman[9] = kirim10;
arrayPengiriman[10] = kirim11;
arrayPengiriman[11] = kirim12;
arrayPengiriman[12] = kirim13;
arrayPengiriman[13] = kirim14;
arrayPengiriman[14] = kirim15;
arrayPengiriman[15] = kirim16;
```

There is also no need to to create an additional Array to hold the very same values for sorting. Why do this if you already have an array? Just sort the original array. The code you are using doesn't sort the Array anyways. It merely displays the elements. You should have a toString() method in your **Pengiriman** class to do this:

To sort the object array you need to determine by what object data you want to sort by in ascending order. Of course the logical choice would be by the Receipt Number (no_resi). To sort an Object by any of its properties, you have to make the Object implement the Comparable interface and override the **compareTo()** method.

```
//Your class must start with:
public class Pengiriman implements Comparable<Pengiriman> {
```

Then somewhere in the Pengiriman class:

```
// Sort by Receipt Number in 'Ascending Order'.
@Override
public int compareTo(Pengiriman comparePengiriman) {
    int compareNoResi = comparePengiriman.getNoResi();

    //ascending order
    return this.no_resi - compareNoResi;

    // If you want Descending order then use this instead:
    // return compareNoResi - this.no_resi;
}
```

Because now you would have a **compareTo()** method within your **Pengiriman** class, to sort the Array you would just need to use this line of code:

```
// Sort the Object Array        
Arrays.sort(arrayPengiriman);
```

Another method you should have within the **Pengiriman** class is the **toString()** method, for example:

```
// Somewhere in the Pengiriman class:
@Override
public String toString() {
    return  no_resi + ", " + nama_pengirim + ", " + alamat_tujuan + 
            ", " + kota_tujuan + ", " + kecamatan_tujuan + ", " + 
            kode_pos_tujuan;
}
```

This method eliminates the need to build a string from all the object data, instead you can do this with a single method call, for example:

```
System.out.println(arrayPengiriman[8].toString());
```

Will display this within the Console Window:

```
101109, Adrian Suta, Jl.Dewi Sartika, Banggai, Luwuk, 94712
```

So with all the above implemented, to display the Array it would be:

```
// Sort the Object Array        
Arrays.sort(arrayPengiriman);

System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
System.out.println("|                                DATA PENGIRIMAN                               |");
System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
System.out.println("");

// Displays the Sorted Array   
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    System.out.print("  " + (i + 1) + ". " + arrayPengiriman[i].toString());
}
```

Now, the **JumpSearch** class. I know we've already touched on a large portion of this class but I would like to concentrate on the **jumpsearch()** method since it is in this particular method where you are having you major problems.

Now, we know how a Jump Search is suppose to work and the fact that it is suppose to work only against **sorted** arrays. There is an order of things and this includes how you implement the conditions for your **while** loops. Take the condition you use for example:

```
while (arrayPengiriman[1 - Math.min(step, n)] < no_resi) {
```

Think about this equation used to acquire the index value for the **arrayPengiriman** array element: `1 - Math.min(step, n)`. Subtract the value of `Math.min(step, n)` **from** the value of **1** which in other words is `1 - (calculated index value)`. What sort of index value do you think you will end up with? Indeed...**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**! What it should be is: subtract **1** from `Math.min(step, n)` or in other words `(calculated index value) - 1`:

```
while (arrayPengiriman[Math.min(step, n) - 1] < no_resi) {
```

But this is only part of the problem with this **while** loop condition. What part of the array are we checking to see if it is less than (<) **no_resi**? The **arrayPengiriman[*n*]** is an object instance of **Pengiriman** and can not be applied to all properties of that instance. You will need to tell it which property of that object instance you want to compare. In this particular case it is the **no_resi** (receipt number) property so you need to do it in this way:

```
while (arrayPengiriman[Math.min(step, n) - 1].getNoResi() < no_resi) {
```

Yes, you need to acquire the Receipt Number for that particular object instance with its' Getter method (**getNoResi()**) so as to check it against the User supplied Receipt Number. As another example, if you happen to want the **sender name** from that particular object instance then you would do something like:

```
String senderName = arrayPengiriman[12].getNamaPengirim();
```

Your second **while** loop in the **jumpsearch()** method contains the wrong condition altogether. It should be:

```
while (arrayPengiriman[prev].getNoResi() < no_resi) {
```

I'm sure this was a copy/paste issue since it was the identical condition as the first **while** loop. :) Remember, this is a linear search in this **while** loop. But notice how the Getter method (**getNoResi()**) was also applied. Your final **IF** statement condition within the **jumpsearch()** method also requires the use of this Getter method:

```
if (arrayPengiriman[prev].getNoResi() == no_resi) {
        return prev;
}
```

I think you get the idea. This should solve your problems.

> The **JumpSearch** Class:

```
public class JumpSearch {

    public static int jumpsearch(Pengiriman[] arrayPengiriman, int no_resi) {
        int n = arrayPengiriman.length;

        // Find the block size to skip
        int step = (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));

        // Finds the block where the element is located
        // present (if element present)
        int prev = 0;
        while (arrayPengiriman[Math.min(step, n) - 1].getNoResi() < no_resi) {
            prev = step;
            step += (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));
            if (prev >= n) {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        // Perform a linear search for x in blocks
        // starts with prev
        while (arrayPengiriman[prev].getNoResi() < no_resi) {
            prev++;

            // If you reach the next or last block
            // array, missing element.
            if (prev == Math.min(step, n)) {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        // If an element is found
        if (arrayPengiriman[prev].getNoResi() == no_resi) {
            return prev;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    // Program for functional testing
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
        System.out.println("|    PROGRAM PENCARIAN DATA PENGIRIMAN BARANG DENGAN ALGORITMA JUMP SEARCH     |");
        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
        System.out.println("|    Case Finding Shipping Data With Recession Using Jump Search Algorithm     |");
        System.out.println("");

        // Array untuk menampung nilai tiap Data
        Pengiriman[] arrayPengiriman = new Pengiriman[16];

        arrayPengiriman[0] = new Pengiriman(101101, "Adam Kamil", "Jl.Anggrek", "Bogor", "Gunungbatu", "16118");
        arrayPengiriman[1] = new Pengiriman(101102, "Putra Mandala", "Jl.Apel", "Kerawang", "Kerawang Barat", "41311");
        arrayPengiriman[2] = new Pengiriman(101103, "Mamat Sanusi", "Jl.Merpati", "Jakarta Selatan", "Lenteng Agung", "12610");
        arrayPengiriman[3] = new Pengiriman(101104, "Kamila Akhwan", "Jl.Kelapa", "Bekasi", "Bekasi Timur", "17111");
        arrayPengiriman[4] = new Pengiriman(101105, "Putra Iskandar", "Jl.Anggrek 2", "Bogor", "Menteng", "16111");
        arrayPengiriman[5] = new Pengiriman(101106, "Nabila Putri", "Jl.Merapi", "Palu", "Tatanga", "94239");
        arrayPengiriman[6] = new Pengiriman(101107, "Imam Satya", "Jl.Pulau Nias", "Manado", "Bunaken", "95231");
        arrayPengiriman[7] = new Pengiriman(101108, "Robby Dermawan", "Jl.Tajung Pura", "Yogyakarta", "Gondokusuman", "55225");
        arrayPengiriman[8] = new Pengiriman(101109, "Adrian Suta", "Jl.Dewi Sartika", "Banggai", "Luwuk", "94712");
        arrayPengiriman[9] = new Pengiriman(1011010, "Rizky Prima", "Jl.Gunung Jati", "Jayawijaya", "Wamena", "99511");
        arrayPengiriman[10] = new Pengiriman(1011011, "Margareth Warouw", "Jl.Sawit", "Jakarta Timur", "Cibubur", "13720");
        arrayPengiriman[11] = new Pengiriman(1011012, "Jeni Indira", "Jl.Tuna", "Bekasi", "Bekasi Barat", "17136");
        arrayPengiriman[12] = new Pengiriman(1011013, "Asep Suratman", "Jl.Palapa", "Bogor", "Margajaya", "16116");
        arrayPengiriman[13] = new Pengiriman(1011014, "Gigi Purnama", "Jl.Keraton Atas", "Bekasi", "Setu", "17320");
        arrayPengiriman[14] = new Pengiriman(1011015, "Kamila Dewi", "Jl.Dago Timur", "Bandung", "Coblong", "40135");
        arrayPengiriman[15] = new Pengiriman(1011016, "Desy Sambeta", "Jl.Proklamasi", "Surabaya", "Wonocolo", "60239");

        // Sort the Object Array        
        Arrays.sort(arrayPengiriman);

        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
        System.out.println("|                                DATA PENGIRIMAN                               |");
        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
        System.out.println("");

        // Displays the Ascending Sorted Array   
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            System.out.println("  " + (i + 1) + ". " + arrayPengiriman[i].toString());
        }

        // Apply the Search Mechanism...
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
        System.out.println("|                               SEARCH SHIPPING DATA                           |");
        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
        System.out.println("");

        // Enter 'noRes'
        System.out.print("    Enter the receipt number you want to search for: ");
        int no_resi = scan.nextInt();

        // Finding index of 'x' with jump search
        int index = jumpsearch(arrayPengiriman, no_resi);

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
        System.out.println("|                       RESULTS OF SHIPPING DATA RESULTS                        |");
        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
        System.out.println("");

        // Displays the index where 'x' is found
        if (no_resi != -1 && index != -1) {
            System.out.println("Shipping data with " + no_resi
                    + " found in index to " + index);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Shipping data with Receipt No " + no_resi
                    + " not found");
        }
        System.out.println("|==============================================================================|");
    }
}
```

> The **Pengiriman** Class:

```
public class Pengiriman implements Comparable<Pengiriman> {

    private int no_resi = 0;
    private String nama_pengirim = "";
    private String alamat_tujuan = "";
    private String kota_tujuan = "";
    private String kecamatan_tujuan = "";
    private String kode_pos_tujuan = "";

    public Pengiriman() {  }

    public Pengiriman(int no_resi, String nama_pengirim, String alamat_tujuan,
            String kota_tujuan, String kecamatan_tujuan, String kode_pos_tujuan) {
        this.no_resi = no_resi;
        this.nama_pengirim = nama_pengirim;
        this.alamat_tujuan = alamat_tujuan;
        this.kota_tujuan = kota_tujuan;
        this.kecamatan_tujuan = kecamatan_tujuan;
        this.kode_pos_tujuan = kode_pos_tujuan;
    }

    public int getNoResi() {
        return no_resi;
    }

    public void setNoResi(int no_resi) {
        this.no_resi = no_resi;
    }

    public String getNamaPengirim() {
        return nama_pengirim;
    }

    public void setNamaPengirim(String nama_pengirim) {
        this.nama_pengirim = nama_pengirim;
    }

    public String getAlamatTujuan() {
        return alamat_tujuan;
    }

    public void setAlamatTujuan(String alamat_tujuan) {
        this.alamat_tujuan = alamat_tujuan;
    }

    public String getKotaTujuan() {
        return kota_tujuan;
    }

    public void setKotaTujuan(String kota_tujuan) {
        this.kota_tujuan = kota_tujuan;
    }

    public String getKecamatanTujuan() {
        return kecamatan_tujuan;
    }

    public void setKecamatanTujuan(String kecamatan_tujuan) {
        this.kecamatan_tujuan = kecamatan_tujuan;
    }

    public String getKodePosTujuan() {
        return kode_pos_tujuan;
    }

    public void setKodePosTujuan(String kode_pos_tujuan) {
        this.kode_pos_tujuan = kode_pos_tujuan;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pengiriman comparePengiriman) {
        int compareNoResi = comparePengiriman.getNoResi();

        //ascending order
        return this.no_resi - compareNoResi;

        // If you want Descending order then use this instead:
        // return compareNoResi - this.no_resi;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return no_resi + ", " + nama_pengirim + ", " + alamat_tujuan
                + ", " + kota_tujuan + ", " + kecamatan_tujuan + ", "
                + kode_pos_tujuan;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you have helped me a lot and great explanation too